# Can I monitor my real hardware CPU, GPU, and HDD temps from inside VMWare Fusion on my Mac?

Tags: linux, mac, temperature, vmware-fusion

I use Linux Mint 13 (a derivative of Debian) as a guest OS under VMWare Fusion on my Mac.

Is there a way to monitor the real CPU, GPU, and hard disk temperatures of my physical hardware in the guest OS?  When I try to add a panel for example it says no sensors found.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see how that could be possible. The guest system has no knowledge of the host and is running on (virtual) hardware that can be completely different to the host hardware.

You could set up some kind of hacky solution, for example, have `sensors` or equivalent run every second on your OSX, saving the output to a file that is accessible from the VM and displaying the file's contents in the guest. I don't think it would be worth the trouble but I could help you set something up if you tell us what app you use for this on OSX and if you have any host folders mounted on the guest system.